# document saves no data after creating on valid data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Below i have given a code for a test REST API.

```
// Imports
var express=require("express")
, mongoose=require("mongoose")
, bodyParser= require('body-parser')
, bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const { Int32 } = require("bson");


// Constants
const app = express()
const PORT=4002

// Our Schema
var data={
    value: Number
}

// Create a model
const dataModel=mongoose.model('dataCollection',mongoose.Schema(data))

// Making connection with database
mongoose.Promise= global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/testdb', {
    useNewUrlParser:true,
    useUnifiedTopology:true
})

// Create the controller to save data
function postData(req,res){
    console.log(req.body)
    let newData = new dataModel(req.body)
    newData.save((err,resp)=>{
        if(err) console.log(err)
        else res.json(resp)
    })
}

// body-parser setup
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));


// express set root page
app.get('/',(req,res)=> res.send("ROOT PAGE"));

// Set Route for our post request
app.route('/app')
.get((req,res)=>res.send("Nothing here"))
.post(postData);

// start listening on server
app.listen(PORT,()=>console.log(`Your application is running on Port: ${PORT}`));
```

Below is the test of POST request test of this code:
[image]

Below is the output produced by Node js:

```
node ./test.js

Your application is running on Port: 4002
{ userName: 'Adnan', UserID: '1', password: '123' }
```

The object below Port number in this output is produced by `console.log(req.body)` in `postData` but the response returned as seen in the screenshot above is an empty object which is stored in the collection instead of actual data.

Comment: The type of your post data is `x-www-form-urlencoded`. Change it to `raw` and add `Content-Type: application/json` header in Postman

Comment: You are not assigning any values to the newData object. "let newData = new dataModel(req.body)"- this line wont store your data in newData object. Try logging newData object and see what values it contains.

Comment: @NaveenChahar this is the output of `console.log(newData)` `{ _id: 5fd0fb760627b4251cc679ef }` , i think you may be right how would i solve this issue

Comment: @kmp it doesn;t work its the same output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not assigning any values to your newData object and your schema is different from the type of data that you are trying to store. Change your code like this:

```
       var data={
        //value: Number
        username: String,
        userId: String,
        password: String
       }

      // Create a model
      const dataModel=mongoose.model('dataCollection',mongoose.Schema(data))

      // Making connection with database
      mongoose.Promise= global.Promise;
      mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/testdb', {
        useNewUrlParser:true,
        useUnifiedTopology:true
      })

     // Create the controller to save data
    function postData(req,res){
     console.log(req.body)
     let newData = new dataModel();
     newData.username=req.body.userName;
     newData.userId=req.body.UserId;
     newData.password=req.body.password;
     newData.save((err,resp)=>{
       if(err) console.log(err)
       else res.json(resp)
     })
   }
```

Comment: The original code worked too i was just trying to (unintentionally) store different data on a different schema. Good eye btw.

Comment: Thx...Is it working now or is there still any problem?

Comment: Happy to help!!